# Unique relations of an object to each other object of the same type

Tags: c#

First, I apologize for the title; I really had no idea how to describe this situation in one line. Say I have a class called `Person`. Multiple instances of `Person` will be created and added to a collection. I am looking for a way to have each instance of `Person` have the potential to 'know' each other person in a literal, real-world sense (`Person` 1 meets `Person` 2, now they know each other) as well as to have a disposition towards each other `Person`.

It seems obvious for an instance of `Person` to use a `bool` for knowing or not knowing another `Person` and to use an `int` for dispositions, though later on I intend to greatly expand upon that. Unfortunately, I really have no idea how to make each `Person` have properties unique to each other in the collection (or perhaps even in a separate collection of the same type). I'm not necessarily looking for code here, but for concepts regarding how to implement something like this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

(Also, if anybody knows of any appropriate tags for this question, please add them or let me know.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a collection of Person objects inside each Person:

```
class Person
{
    List<Person> Knows; // People this person knows
}
```

The `Knows` list will only keep an object reference so you're not duplicating data there.

Comment: +1 For simplicity. I was thinking too much into this.

Comment: Wow, that's far easier than I was making it. As far as having a property for disposition of something of that nature goes, how would I go about handling that?

Comment: If you want to store attributes such as disposition then you could make it a `Dictionary` instead, where the "person he/she knows" is the key and the attributes are the data.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for your help!